# Design a circuit for a light fixture

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Design a circuit for a light fixture controlled by four
switches, where flipping one of the switches turns the
light on when it is off and turns it off when it is on
and please explain your answer

Comment: I want to make it by using truth table and sum of products

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

Use switches of the following type: There are two input terminals $A$, $B$ and two output terminals $A'$, $B'$. The switch either makes the connections $A-A'$, $B-B'$ or the connections $A-B'$, $B-A'$.